# Can Classic ASP pages run in Azure?

Tags: asp-classic, azure

I'm looking into Azure and unsure if Classic ASP (i.e. ASP 3.0 with .ASP extensions) can run in Azure?

I found [this blog post](http://www.shanmcarthur.net/cloud-services/azure-tips/asp-pages-throw-404-errors) from January 2009 indicating Classic ASP can NOT be run in Azure.  But on this [interoperability page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/interop/) it looks like now, other platforms like PHP can be run on Azure.  I still see no mention of Classic ASP though.

Can Classic ASP pages run in Azure?

Comment: You can now run classic ASP on an azure webapps out of the box.  It just works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, but as soon as the new "virtual machine role" becomes available, you'll be able to configure your own virtual server(s) to support classic ASP. No timeline given AFAIK, but "soon" has been mentioned.

These servers will run on the Azure hardware, but they won't run the Azure Guest OS 1.x, so you cannot easily use Azure features like Storage or AppFabric... then again, you might not want to from a classic ASP environment :-)

*EDIT*: at the time of asking my answer was correct (there was no full IIS available), but a lot has changed, so the answer in 2012 would definitely be "yes", as detailed below.

Comment: Thanks for this info and the keyword "virtual machine role".  Found a little extra information Googling on this.

Comment: Classic ASP can most definitely be run on Windows Azure WITHOUT waiting for virtual machine role.
You can configure classic ASP through a simple cmd executed as a startup task when the role starts.

Answer (score 8):

Check this out - http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-31-Startup-Tasks-Elevated-Privileges-and-Classic-ASP, at about 15 minutes in they tell you how to run Classic Asp in Azure

The actual startup command is at 23:51 within the video.

I've tried replicating the code that they have on the show but I get an error -     "CloudServices64 : Cannot find file named 'approot\bin\startup.cmd'" for startup task startup.cmd  when I try to build the project. Hopefully its just me and you'll have better luck.

To solve the error "CloudService...." - have a look at http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/gg456327.aspx It tells you that you need set the properties on the file to "copy to output directory"  to always

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the instructions for enabling it are here:

http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/running-classic-asp-on-azure/

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You can attempt to get around recoding your ASP pages with something like the [ASP Classic Compiler](http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for including the same link I already posted.  That's an old January 2009 post.  A lot has changed with Azure in the last year (for example, PHP can now be run where it couldn't before).  Is it still the case TODAY that classic ASP won't run on Azure?

Comment: Removed the repetative link since it's apparently bad form to link to the answer that Ben had but couldn't believe. @John, I'm not sure what you want out of an answer.

Comment: @Ben there's no evidence that Azure has added classic ASP support, so yeah, a post from January 2009 is still relavent. Information does not get outdated due to it's age, it gets outdated when new information is found.

Comment: +1 For ASP Compiler, this may well be the route to moving legacy code on to Azure, of course that probably won't make sense unless there are Managed implementations of the typical ADO interfaces used in ASP.

Comment: @jball: an answer that repeats the question isn't an answer. That part of your answer, wasn't. Downvote removed.

Comment: classic ASP is definitely something that is fully supported in Windows Azure. It's a simple start-up task.